# breakdown by weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

Below is a simple query and the result: Is the a way to aggregate the total EVENTs by 7 days, then sum up the total EVENTs? Would a rollup function work? I am using SQL SERVER 05 & 08. Thanks again, folks.

```
SELECT DATE_SOLD, count(DISTINCT PRODUCTS) AS PRODUCT_SOLD    
FROM PRODUCTS    
WHERE DATE >='10/1/2009' 
and DATE <'10/1/2010'
GROUP BY DATE_SOLD
```

RESULTS:

```
DATE_SOLD            PRODUCT_SOLD
10/1/09          5
10/2/09          11
10/3/09          14
10/4/09          6
10/5/09          11
10/6/09          13
10/7/09          10
Total              70

10/8/09          4
10/9/09          11
10/10/09             8
10/11/09             4
10/12/09             7
10/13/09             4
10/14/09             9
Total              47
```

Comment: are you trying to get a result that looks like a report, like you have in your sample, or do you want the result of you query to just be totals?

Comment: I would like the query to be totaled first, then the the output like the sample above.

Comment: Can you post the SQL used to create the table "MYTABLE". It would make it easier to see what you are trying to do. You should also consider using different fields names as DATE and EVENTS are keywords in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Not having your table design to work with here's what I think you are after (although I have to admit the output needs to be cleaned up). It should, at least, get you some way to the solution you are looking for.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable( 
event_date date,
event_type char(1)
)
GO

INSERT MyTable VALUES ('2009-1-01', 'A')
INSERT MyTable VALUES ('2009-1-11', 'B')
INSERT MyTable VALUES ('2009-1-11', 'C')
INSERT MyTable VALUES ('2009-1-20', 'N')
INSERT MyTable VALUES ('2009-1-20', 'N')
INSERT MyTable VALUES ('2009-5-23', 'D')
INSERT MyTable VALUES ('2009-5-23', 'E')
INSERT MyTable VALUES ('2009-5-10', 'F')
INSERT MyTable VALUES ('2009-5-10', 'F')
GO

WITH T AS (
    SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, event_date) event_month, event_date, event_type 
    FROM MyTable
)   

SELECT CASE WHEN (GROUPING(event_month) = 0) 
            THEN event_month ELSE '99' END AS event_month,
       CASE WHEN (GROUPING(event_date) = 1) 
            THEN '9999-12-31' ELSE event_date END AS event_date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT event_type) AS event_count
FROM T
GROUP BY event_month, event_date WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY event_month, event_date
```

This gives the following output:

```
event_month event_date event_count
1           2009-01-01      1
1           2009-01-11      2
1           2009-01-20      1
1           9999-12-31      4
5           2009-05-10      1
5           2009-05-23      2
5           9999-12-31      3
99          9999-12-31      7
```

Where the '99' for month and '9999-12-31' for year are the totals.

Comment: Sorry, have just realised I have given the breakdown by month and not week, I must be tired. I'm sure you can edit the code to make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(week, 0, DATE_SOLD) Week,
    DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, DATE_SOLD), 0) From,
    DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, DATE_SOLD), 0) + 6 To,
    COUNT(DISTINCT PRODUCTS) PRODUCT_SOLD
FROM dbo.PRODUCTS
WHERE DATE >= '2009-10-01' 
    AND DATE < '2010-10-01'
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(week, 0, DATE_SOLD) WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(week, 0, DATE_SOLD)
```